# Set a image age restriction when using UIimagePickerViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

When using UIimagePickerViewcontroller, is it possible to let the user only select images from within the latest month, or from ONLY, say, month 10 of the year?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code as well as what solutions you might have tried.

Comment: my code is just a button that opens the image picker. standard stuff.

but when that picker opens, i want only pictures from the past month to appear.. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html) API that would allow that. For that level of control, you'll probably need to write your own picker. You can use the [Assets Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) to find the images you want the user to pick from.

Before you do that, though, remember that the best apps *enable* users to do what they want rather than *constraining* them to a developer's preconceptions about how the app should be used. That's not to say that there can't be a legitimate reason to limit the images that the user can pick, but it might be worth thinking about ways to avoid creating a limitation.

If you decide that you really do want to filter the images that the user can pick from, know that there are many third-party replacements for `UIImagePickerController`. I didn't look very long before I found [`ELCImagePickerController`](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController), which appears to allow filtering. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: One more thing to add, Assets Library is outdated. On iOS 8 and Above Apple prefers to use Photos Framework instead of Assets Library. Photos framework have a lot of options for filtering and it's performance is much better than Assets Library. Refer : [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)

Comment: @MidhunMP That's true, and it's mentioned prominently at the top of the Assets Library document. But the OP doesn't specify a particular iOS version, so I chose not to limit to iOS 8. The Assets Library doesn't appear to be deprecated yet, so it should be safe to use for some time to come even if it doesn't provide all the features that the Photos framework does.

Comment: @Caleb: I agree with you, he tagged swift. So I thought OP is looking for iOS 8+ solutions. Asset Library not deprecated, but Photos Framework have much better performance (Some cool stuffs like, it'll give you two images a thumbnail and original image, thumbnail for showing when it is loading the original image and some other features like that). Your answer is 100% correct, I just added one more option for iOS 8 and 8+ :)